# Type inference discrepancy between method and extension method arguments

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's say I have the following method defined:

```
int ReturnNumber(int number)
{
    return number;
}
```

Now, let's say that I also have the following two methods defined; a regular method:

`void Print(Func<int, int> function)`

and an extension method:

`static void Print(this Func<int, int> function)`

I can call the former like this:

`Print(ReturnNumber); // Regular method call, seems to implicitly convert ReturnNumber to Func<int, int>`

but I can't do that with the latter:

`ReturnNumber.Print(); // Extension method call, does not seem to do the implicit conversion -- results in compiler error`

though I can do this:

`((Func<int, int>)ReturnNumber).Print(); // I perform the conversion explicitly`

I'm assuming that there's some "magic" that happens when you pass a method as an argument to another method, and that the compiler is therefore able to guess that it should try to convert the `ReturnNumber` to `Func<int, int>`, whereas the compiler doesn't do any such thing for extension methods.  Is this correct?  My question can be summarized as: why can't you call an extension method on a method, whereas you can call an extension method on a delegate instance?  Does it have something to do with the fact that the compiler doesn't treat methods as objects, but only treats delegates as objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method group can be *implicitly converted* to `Func<int, int>`, which means if you're using that method group in a location where a `Func<int, int>` is expected (such as by passing it to a method who's parameter is `Func<int, int>` then it's able to convert it into such a delegate.

But until you've actually converted that method group into a `Func<int, int>` you can't call any instance methods on it, as it has none.  When you explicitly cast it to a `Func<int, int>` then you're changing that expression from a method group (which isn't itself a `Func<int, int>`) into a `Func<int, int>`.